# How to format column length on select query in oracle 11g?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have problem in formatting column length using select query in oracle 11g. This is my table structure :
[image]

I'm trying to format judul_buku length into 50, but it seems didn't work when im using RPAD syntax.
This is my query :

```
SELECT rpad(b.judul_buku, 50) as "Buku"
from buku b;
```

This is the output (came out wrong because the length is more than 50).
[image]

I have tried to search how to format column length from select query but i can't find the right keyword to search it so i can't find any syntax to change column length.

I'm using oracle 11g and i can't change the version since my lecturer told me to use oracle 11g and she only teach RPAD and LPAD to reduce column length (which didn't work for me and my friend).

Is there any other way to reduce column length instead RPAD LPAD ?

Comment: `col buku format a50`

Comment: @WilliamRobertson i just put that syntax before select query ?

Comment: In SQL\*Plus you apply all your formatting using `column`, `linesize` etc settings as part of your script ([see docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/formatting-SQL-Plus-reports.html)). Put the commands wherever you want. Note this is all specific to the SQL\*Plus tool and doesn't apply to Oracle or SQL in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about casting to `char(50)`?

```
select cast(b.judul_buku as char(50)) as "Buku"
from buku b;
```

This sets the type and pads the value with 50 spaces if the value is shorter.  That said, this type of formatting is usually done in the application.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what im looking for :)

Comment: cast to varchar2 also works in SQL\*Plus (because it detect the datatype) and avoids breaking the "Never Use CHAR Ever" rule :)